# Repeater data inside template column of radgrid does not show when we do export to CSV

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a RadGrid to display subscribers list and a repeater control with two fields. Repeater is placed inside template column of grid when I click on export to csv button of grid then other column of grid are export but template column with repeater not.
Could anyone please help me?

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Email Address/Verified Status" DataField="SubscriberEmailAddress"
    Groupable="false" AllowFiltering="false" UniqueName="SubscriberEmailAddress">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="EmailAddressRepeater" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 80%;">
                            <asp:Label ID="EmailAddressLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("News_Subscriber_Email_Map_Email_Address") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="EmailAddressVerifiedCheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("News_Subscriber_Log_Verified_Status").ToString())%>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Wrap="false" Width="20%" />
    <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Top" HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="false" Width="20%" />
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSV is text-Based format it doesn't support complex structures like tables.